# SFScheduler appointment font size

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, syncfusion, sfschedule

I am using `SfSchedule` for iOS and C#, and I can't find out how to change an appointment font size.

Must be something kind of simple but after trying to search all around I still can't figure how to do it.

Comment: Please include the code you have tried, and what error message or undesirable behavior you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

We can customize the schedule appointment by using AppointmentStyle Property of SFSchedule or AppointmentLoaded event in SFSchedule.

We can change the font size of schedule appointment by setting through the TextStyle of AppointmentStyle property. Please find the below code example for above the same,

Customizing through AppointmentLoaded event,

```
void Schedule_AppointmentLoaded(object sender, AppointmentLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    e.AppointmentStyle.TextStyle = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
}
```

Customizing through AppointmentStyle property,

```
SFAppointmentStyle appointmentstyle = new SFAppointmentStyle();
appointmentstyle.TextStyle = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(20);
schedule.AppointmentStyle = appointmentstyle;
```